# На каком методе завис код?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть следующий код отправки фото через ВК API:

```
def send_photo(user_id, pref, message='', words='', count=0):
    if count > 5: #один из костылей, который мешает перейти в рекурсию
        return
    try:
        photo_id = ''

        # Получаем ссылку для загрузки изображений
        method_url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?'
        data = dict(access_token=key)
        response = req.post(method_url, data)
        result = response.json()
        upload_url = result['response']['upload_url']
        # Перебираем префиксы и загружаем фото на сервера ВК
        for pht in pref:
            img = {'photo': ('pibot_photo.png', open(r'{}_result.png'.format(path_home_dir + pht), 'rb'))}
            # Загружаем изображение на url
            response = req.post(upload_url, files=img)
            result = response.json()
            method_url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveMessagesPhoto?'
            data = dict(access_token=key, gid=group_id, photo=result['photo'], hash=result['hash'],
                        server=result['server'])
            response = req.post(method_url, data)
            print(response.json)
            photo_id += 'photo' + str(json.loads(response.text)['response'][0]['owner_id']) + '_' + str(
                json.loads(response.text)['response'][0]['pid']) + ','
        # Отправка фото с сообщением
        user_id = str(user_id)

        frt = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'
        data = dict(user_id=user_id, message=words, attachment=photo_id, access_token=key, v=5.62)
        # Начала костыля. Рекурсионно отправляю сообщение
        def send_photo_by_id(ct):
            if ct > 5:
                return
            try:
                req.post(frt, data, timeout=3)
                send_photo_by_id(0)
                cover_update(message, user_id, ima=pref[0])
            except req.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
                send_photo_by_id(ct+1)


    except Exception as Err:
        send('Ошибка при загрузке фото. Мы уже знаем о ней и скоро исправим', user_id)
        log_send('error_send_photo', traceback.format_exc(), '', user_id)
        send_photo(user_id, pref, message=message, words=words, count=count+1)
```

Проблема в том, что где-то в этом методе скрипт зависает. Как отловить метод, где это происходит? Скорее всего, уходит в рекурсию, но почему?

Comment: Попробуйте нажать Ctrl-C и посмотреть в tracelog'е

Comment: А где вы инкрементируете переменные `count` и `ct`?

Comment: @pinguin Да, count не отсюда, но с ним нормально. А ct - send_photo_by_id(ct+1)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Всё не так легко, это всё в большом приложении, а баг воспроизвести сложно. Не получится дождаться и нажать ctrl+c

Comment: @vladF вы передаете в функцию `ct+1`, но само значение вы не изменяете

Comment: @vladF И где у вас внешний запуск функции `send_photo_by_id`? Именно не рекурсивный запуск, а точка входа в рекурсию?

Comment: @pinguin да, ошибка, это я уже тут писал, в коде все нормально (в этом плане). Вход в функцию находится в нескольких методах, которым нужно отправить фото